# Youtube video upload to playlist

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-data-api

I have used youtube GTL to upload video in youtube. Video is uploaded successfully but know i have problem is i cant move that video to any particular playlist in youtube i have problem with resourceID its null.

```
GTLYouTubePlaylistItem *playlistitem = [[GTLYouTubePlaylistItem alloc] init];
GTLYouTubePlaylistItemSnippet *playlistitemSnippet = [GTLYouTubePlaylistItemSnippet object];
GTLYouTubeResourceId* resourceObject = [GTLYouTubeResourceId object];

playlistitemSnippet.playlistId = playlist_ID;

resourceObject.kind = @"youtube#playlistItem";
resourceObject.videoId = videoID;
[playlistitemSnippet setResourceId:resourceObject];
playlistitemSnippet.resourceId = resourceObject;

GTLQueryYouTube *query1 = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForPlaylistItemsInsertWithObject:playlistitem part:@"snippet"];
```